# unique() or duplicated() with all.equal() functionality?

Tags: r

I am searching for a (simple) function in R to remove duplicated elements, like `unique()` or `duplicated()` which can consider for "near equality" of numerical values like `all.equal()`:

```
unique( c(0, 0))
[1] 0
```

works fine, but

```
unique( c(0, cos(pi/2)) )
[1] 0.000000e+00 6.123032e-17
```

does not remove the second element, although a comparison with all.equal returns TRUE:

```
all.equal( 0, cos(pi/2) )
[1] TRUE
```

Same is valid for duplicated:

```
duplicated( c(0, cos(pi/2)))
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to take into account the absolute error, and not the relative error (as `all.equal` does), try:

```
x <- c(0, cos(pi/2), 1, 1+1e-16)
unique(x)
## [1] 0.000000e+00 6.123234e-17 1.000000e+00
(x <- x[!duplicated(round(x, 10))])
## [1] 0 1
```

Here we remove the elements that are the same w.r.t. a fixed (10 above) number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider the `zapsmall` function:

```
x <- rep(c(1,2), each=5) + rnorm(10)/(10^rep(1:5,2))
unique(x)
# [1] 1.0571484 1.0022854 1.0014347 0.9998829 0.9999985 2.1095720 1.9888208 2.0002687 1.9999723 2.0000078

unique(zapsmall(x, digits=4))
# [1] 1.0571 1.0023 1.0014 0.9999 1.0000 2.1096 1.9888 2.0003 2.0000
unique(zapsmall(x, digits=2))
# [1] 1.06 1.00 2.11 1.99 2.00
unique(zapsmall(x, digits=0))
# [1] 1 2
```

Comment: `zapsmall` does not work in this case:  `> x <- c (0, cos(pi/2))  > unique( zapsmall(x, 1))  [1] 0e+00 6e-17`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code (disclaimer: from my package `cgwtools`)

```
 approxeq <- function (x, y, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps^0.5, ...) 
{
    if (length(x) != length(y)) 
        warning("x,y lengths differ. Will recycle.")
    checkit <- abs(x - y) < tolerance
    return(invisible(checkit))
}
```